# Sign in definition of polarization of Hodge structure

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, hodge-theory

Let $H_{\mathbb{Z}}$ be an integral Hodge structure of weight $n$ with Hodge decomposition
$H_{\mathbb{C}} = \sum_{p+q=n}H^{p, q}$.

In the definition of a polarized Hodge structure, I have come across two different definitions that differ by a sign (periodic every 4).  For example, in Voisin's book it is defined as a $(-1)^n$ symmetric bilinear form $Q$ that is $0$ unless operating on conjugate degrees in the Hodge decomposition, and satisfying

$$i^{p-q}(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}Q(\alpha, \overline{\alpha})>0$$
with nonzero $\alpha\in H^{p, q}$.  In various other sources, e.g. [http://www.math.columbia.edu/~rf/VHS.pdf](http://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Erf/VHS.pdf), the last condition is simply replaced with
$$i^{p-q}Q(\alpha, \overline{\alpha})>0.$$

Can someone explain the discrepancy in the factor $(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ between these two definitions?

Edit: Looking closer I realized that in Voisin's definition, the domain is restricted to the primitive cohomology $H^{p,q}_{pr}$.  However, my question still remains.

Comment: Personally I guess that in Voisin's case: Given a compact Kähler manifold $X$ of complex dimension $n$, an obvious choice for $Q$ on $H^n(X)$ (or its subspace $H^n(X)_{pr}$) is $Q([\alpha],[\beta])=\int_X\alpha\wedge \beta$, where $\alpha,\beta$ are suitable smooth $n$-forms on $X$. This choice calls for a sign $(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}$ to get positivity.